# How to join table with another that have count?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have first table where i made this count :

```
SELECT TYPEC ,count(TYPEC) 
FROM planning_cuisson 
GROUP BY TYPEC 
HAVING COUNT(TYPEC) > 0 
ORDER BY COUNT(TYPEC) asc
```

and show this values :

[image]

and i have an other table named zp01 that have a colonne same as TYPEC that's TYPE_CUISSON.

[image]

how can i get this result with a join between tables =>
[image]

i tryed this requette but didnt work :

```
SELECT * 
FROM planning_cuisson p1, zp01 p2 
WHERE p2.type_cuisson=p1.typec 
GROUP BY p1.TYPEC 
HAVING COUNT(p1.TYPEC) > 0 
ORDER BY COUNT(p1.TYPEC) asc
```

Comment: I advise you to use 'modern' joins as in here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use join like this:

```
SELECT p2.*, p1.cnt_typec 
FROM zp01 p2 
JOIN (
  SELECT TYPEC, count(TYPEC) AS cnt_typec 
  FROM planning_cuisson 
  GROUP BY TYPEC 
  HAVING COUNT(TYPEC) > 0
) p1
WHERE p2.type_cuisson = p1.typec 
ORDER BY cnt_typec ASC;
```

In the inner query, you get those records for which count of typec is > 0 and then join those records with `zp01` table to get the desired records.

Comment: can you translate this sql to jpql i tried but i failed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623376/how-to-translate-sql-query-to-jpql-query

Comment: @marouanoviche unfortunately i dont have any experience with jpql